# Could not contact Selenium Server; have you started it on 'localhost:4444'?

Tags: selenium, testng, functional-testing

I am using selenium standalone version `2.33.0` to run the automated test cases. It was running fine until last month. The firefox version then was `21.x`. Now it is upgraded to `ver-22`.

I figured out that selenium `2.33` does not work with the latest firefox browser. So I changed the value of 'maxVersion' to `23.0.*` in the below files:

```
./customProfileDirCUSTFF/extensions/readystate@openqa.org/install.rdf
./customProfileDirCUSTFF/extensions/{538F0036-F358-4f84-A764-89FB437166B4}/install.rdf
./customProfileDirCUSTFFCHROME/extensions/readystate@openqa.org/install.rdf
./customProfileDirCUSTFFCHROME/extensions/{503A0CD4-EDC8-489b-853B-19E0BAA8F0A4}/install.rdf
./customProfileDirCUSTFFCHROME/extensions/{538F0036-F358-4f84-A764-89FB437166B4}/install.rdf
```

After this when I try to run selenium, I get the below error:

```
Could not contact Selenium Server; have you started it on 'localhost:4444' ? Read more at http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/not-started.html Connection refused

com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:86) 
at qa.apigee.common.ApigeeOnlineUITestBase.launchBrowser(Unknown Source) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.invokeMethod(MethodHelper.java:640) 
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:503) 
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:193) 
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:123) 
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:183) 
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:115) 
at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1098) 
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:727) 
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:581) 
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:315) 
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:310) 
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:272) 
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:221) 
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:40) 
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:83) 
at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$CountDownLatchedRunnable.run(ThreadUtil.java:151) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the below code to start the server.

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://www.google.com/");
    selenium.start();
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry but this is not working. And giving same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. You can change the port number as follows:

Goto run-> ExternalTools ->ExternalToolsConfiguration->update the "arguments" as below:

```
-jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2 jar -port 1234     ->apply-> run
```

After making this, change the port num as 1234 in your program, save the program and run.

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to start the server:

You should go to the directory where Selenium RC’s server is located and run the following from a command-line console:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-<version-number>.jar
```

You can also create a .bat on Windows o .sh on Linux

Source: Running selenium server (http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.jsp)